# How do I apply css to iframe where the src is PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, echo

I want to apply css to a piece of php code that my html page calls as an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://ktibclaims.co.uk/claimStats.php" frameborder="0" width="850" name="frame1" style="color:#ffffff;" ></iframe>
```

I have control over the php file but am not a php programmer. All I want to do is force the echo text that is generated on my html page to display in the correct font styling to match the rest of my page. I have tried several suggestions on this site about applying inline styles directly to the php but it doesn't seem to work. The php file contains only php and it is in its entirety as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('Class.ClaimStats.php');

$claimStats = new ClaimStats();
$totalClaims = $claimStats->getTotalClaimsCount();

echo "We donate &pound;1 to East Coast Truckers for every new claim reported using our     online claims system. There have been " . $totalClaims . " claims so far!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it by adding some CSS classes to that PHP file and then use those classes in your stylesheet.

```
<?php
require_once('Class.ClaimStats.php');

$claimStats = new ClaimStats();
$totalClaims = $claimStats->getTotalClaimsCount();

echo "<span class='donatestyle' style='color: #FFF;'>We donate &pound;1
    to East Coast Truckers for every new claim reported using our online
    claims system. There have been $totalClaims claims so far!</span>";
?>
```

And then where you calling the `<iframe />`:

```
<style>
span.donatestyle {color:#F00;}
</style>
<iframe src="http://ktibclaims.co.uk/claimStats.php"
        frameborder="0"
        width="850"
        name="frame1"
        style="color:#FFF;">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Many Thanks Houssni, you have solved my problem - guess I ought to go and learn some php...

Answer (score 0):

You can place HTML tags in your php file either!

So you can do:

```
<?php
    require_once('Class.ClaimStats.php');

    $claimStats = new ClaimStats();
    $totalClaims = $claimStats->getTotalClaimsCount();
?>
<span class="cssClass" style="your: inlineStyle;">We donate &pound;1 to East Coast Truckers for every new claim reported using our     online claims system. There have been <?php echo $totalClaims; ?> claims so far!</span>
```